# navbar with changing layout xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to have a navbar ( just some layout with buttons ) at the bottom of the app and pressing one of the buttons will change the layout/screen that's located above the navbar. how would this be achieved? would I still have to create separate activities for each screen and just have the navbar on each screen? or is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found an answer, Tabbed Pages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page

Answer (score 0):

But you should be aware that using the tabbed page will display the tab bar at the bottom in iOS. In Android tabbed bar will always appear at the top.

If you need to build a tab bar which appears at the bottom in both the platforms (iOS and Android) you have to design your own layout.

I've done a custom layout to achieve this, let me know if you need the code, I can post it here.

Comment: that would be helpful